# Injecting table into specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I generate this table it is generated after the rest of the code is executed.

I want to be able to generate the code into a specific class like ".container".

How would I do this?

```
var listOfWords = [];
var rndWord = [];
var counter = 0;
var ul = document.getElementById("wordlist");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < ul.children.length; ++i) {

    listOfWords.push({
        "name": ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-word"),
        "pic": ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-pic"),
        "audio": ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-audio")
    });
}

var chosenWords = [];
var copylist = listOfWords.slice();

for (var x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (copylist.length));
    chosenWords.push(copylist[rand].name);
    copylist.splice(rand, 1);
    if (chosenWords.length < 12) {
    chosenWords.push('   ');
   }

}

var shuffledWords = [];
shuffledWords = chosenWords.sort(function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random()
});

var guesses = {};
var tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.className = 'tablestyle';
var wordsPerRow = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < shuffledWords.length - 1; i += wordsPerRow) {

    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = i; j < i + wordsPerRow; ++j) {
        var word = shuffledWords[j];
        guesses[word] = [];

         for (var k = 0; k < word.length; ++k) {
            var cell = document.createElement('td');


            $(cell).addClass('drop-box').attr('data-word', word).attr('data-letter',         word[k]);
            cell.textContent = word[k];

            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }
    tbl.appendChild(row);
}

document.body.appendChild(tbl);
```

I thought changing the bottom line of this code from

```
document.body.appendChild(tbl);
```

to

```
document.container.appendChild(tbl);
```

would do it but it didn't.

Does anyone know how to put this table into container?

Comment: What is container? Is it a class of some element or an id of some element?

Comment: Only if container is an id you can access it using document.container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add the table to an element with a specific css class, you can do the following.

```
$(".container").append(tbl);
```